# AJAX shows data passed as HTML but not JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

When an item in main cat clicked, all sub items related to that particular id are shown in `showSubCat` div. Data are fetched from searchItems.php via AJAX and this works fine only if dataType is set to html/text. The result shown as below:

```
[{"name":"Martial Arts","id":"4"},{"name":"Fitness","id":"5"},{"name":"Dance","id":"6"},{"name":"Lifestyle","id":"7"}]
```

But I'm expecting JSON datatype.But when I change the dataType in AJAX request to `json`, nothing shown.I just would like to understand what does it expect to define a dataset as JSON? PLease check my php script in searchItems.php and let me know, what I should do so that it can accept it as JSON.

The reason being, I want to be able to retrieve only data I wanted, by placing like this in the AJAX success function:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             console.log(data[i].name);
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Html

```
<!--Main Cat ends-->
    <div class="main_cat" id="<?php echo $value["id"];?>">
        <?php
        echo $value["name"];
        ?>
    </div>
  <!--Main Cat ends-->



<!--sub Cat starts-->
  <div id="showSubCat">
  <h2>Sub categories</h2>
  </div>
  <!--sub Cat ends-->
```

script

```
$(".main_cat").on("click",function()
{
    var id = this.id;
    $('#showSubCat').empty();
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'searchItems.php?id='+id,
      success: function(data){
           $('#showSubCat').append(data);

      }
    });
});
```

searchItems.php

```
 <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'config.php');?>
 <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class.search_functions.php');?>
 <?php
  $id = $_GET["id"];
  $subCat = new searchItems();
  $showSubCat = $subCat->showSubCat($id);
  $json=array();
  foreach($showSubCat as $key=>$value)
  {
     array_push($json,array("name"=>$value["name"],"id"=>$value["id"]));
  }

   echo json_encode($json);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
dataType: "html",
```

to

```
dataType: "json",
```

in your [**$.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) parameters.

This `dataType` is the data format of the data that is returned from the server.

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

Comment: I said when I change the dataType to JSON it doesn't show anything!

Answer (score 0):

My edited Script that works as expected:

```
$(".main_cat").on("click",function()
{
    var id = this.id;
    $('#showSubCat').empty();
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'searchItems.php?id='+id,
      success: function(data){
         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 console.log(data[i].name);
                  $('#showSubCat').append(data[i].name);
            }
      }
    });
});
```